# How do I get all retweets or the retweeters of my own personal tweet?

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweets

I know you must be thinking that its impossible or its been asked already.

But I have 2 queries. The first is that by using Twitter API, using an access token of my own profile, can I get all (more than 100) the retweets of my own tweet? Not someone else's, as all previous questions at stackoverflow have been asked.
Because there's a difference in private and public tweet and getting data related to it.

Secondly, if we cannot get more than 100 retweets, then how does this app Pickaw (formerly Twrench) https://pickaw.com/en gets all the retweets even if they're more than 500 and the corresponding data?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API only provides access to up to 100 Retweeters (IDs for users that RT'd a Tweet), regardless of whether this is your owned Tweet, or another one.

As for a specific app, it is only possible to speculate, unless the source code was Open Source and available. I would suggest there are two ways to get all the Retweets:

- pay for premium or enterprise search access, and use the advanced PowerTrack rules to find Retweets of a specific Tweet ID;
- use the Account Activity API webhooks to track whenever a user's Tweet is Retweeted. Not that this would only work in a real-time tracking case; you wouldn't be able to check historical Tweets.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was reading about the enterprise search access. Does that enable us to get all the retweets? Since twitter is not allowing more than 100.